# If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of $x^3+x+1=0$, then find the equation whose roots are: $(\alpha-\beta)^2,(\beta-\gamma)^2,(\gamma-\alpha)^2$

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

**Question:**

> If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of the equation, $x^3+x+1=0$, then find the equation whose roots are: $({\alpha}-{\beta})^2,({\beta}-{\gamma})^2,({\gamma}-{\alpha})^2$

Now, the normal way to solve this question would be to use the theory of equations and find the sum of roots taken one at a time, two at a time and three at a time. Using this approach, we get the answer as $(x+1)^3+3(x+1)^2+27=0$. However, I feel that this is a very lengthy approach to this problem. Is there an easier way of doing it?

Comment: I think your approach is pretty straightforward and thus the quickest (you may have to think for other approaches, it takes time)). Also as $x^3=-x-1$ for $\alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma$ you could use this lowering of exponent in the solution.

Comment: As it's a depressed cubic, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$ : I wonder if that can be exploited somehow... Also $\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=-\alpha\beta\gamma$ so, yes, I can see why you are asking...$\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3=3\alpha\beta\gamma$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin this approach also takes a lot time

Comment: @MartinHansen yes exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ be the roots of $x^3+x+1=0$ so we have $a+b+c=0, ab+bc+ca=1,abc=-1$, so $a^2+b^2+c^2=-2$ and $c^3=-c-1$

We would explore a transformation from $x$ to $y$ to get the required cubic equation of $y$.
Let $$y=(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\implies y=-2-c^2+2/c \implies c=\frac{3}{1+y}$$
Replacing $c$ by $x$ we get the required transformation $x=\frac{3}{1+y}$, putting it in the given $x$ equation, we get:
$$\frac{27}{(1+y)^3}+\frac{3}{(1+y)}+1=0 \implies y^3+6y^2+9y+31=0,$$
which is the required cubic equation.

Comment: Could you please explain $$y=2-c^2+2/c \implies c=\frac{3}{c-3}$$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Sorry there was a typo it should be $c=3/(y-3)$. See the edit please.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc I'm sorry, but why do you take $y=(a-b)^2$?

Comment: @General Kenobi this is the method of transformation  when the new roots are symmetric function of old roots $a,b,c$ we set the new root as $y$ and try to write$y$ in terms of only $a,b,c$. So here we write $y$ in terms of $c$ and get $c$ as a function of $y$. Finally we set $c$ as $x$ put it in the $x$-equation. We get the required cubic.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Final constant term $1+3+27=31$ can be obtained at once (or checked at once) by considering that it is the opposite of the product of roots

$$(({\alpha}-{\beta})({\beta}-{\gamma})({\gamma}-{\alpha}))^2$$

which is the classical **discriminant** $-(4p^3+27q^2)$ of a reduced 3rd degree equation $X^3+pX+q=0$ with $p=q=1$.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $y=(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab=(-c)^2-\dfrac4{-c}$ as $abc=-1, a+b=-c$

$$\iff c^3-cy+4=0\ \ \ \  (1) $$

Again we have $$c^3+c+1=0\ \ \ \ (0)$$

Solve the two simultaneous equations for $c,c^3$ and use $c^3=(c)^3$ to eliminate $c$

Answer (score 2):

The standard method:
$$a+b+c=0; ab+bc+ca=1; abc=-1;\\
a^2+b^2+c^2=-2;a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2=1;a^4+b^4+c^4=2;\\
a^3=-a-1.$$
First coefficient:
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=\\2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-2(ab+bc+ca)=-6$$
Second coefficient:
$$(a-b)^2(b-c)^2+(b-c)^2(c-a)^2+(c-a)^2(a-b)^2=\\
a^4+b^4+c^4+3(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)-\\
2(a^3(\underbrace{b+c}_{-a})+b^3(\underbrace{c+a}_{-b})+c^3(\underbrace{a+b}_{-c}))=\\
3(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+a^4+b^4+c^4)=9$$
Third coefficient:
$$(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2=\\
\small{(a^2+b^2-2ab)(b^2+c^2-2bc)(c^2+a^2-2ac)=\\
(c^2-4ab)(a^2-4bc)(b^2-4ac)=\\
16 a^4 b c - 4 a^3 b^3 - 4 a^3 c^3 - 63 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 16 a b^4 c + 16 a b c^4 - 4 b^3 c^3=\\
-16(a^3+b^3+c^3)-4(a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3)-63=\\
-16(-a-b-c-3)-4((-a-1)(-b-1)+\\
(-b-1)(-c-1)+(-c-1)(-a-1))-63=}\\
48-4(1+3)-63=-31.$$
Hence, the equation is: $x^3+6x^2+9x+31=0$.